# How to open existing .java in eclipse (like BufferedImage specification)

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

this might a stupid question but I can't find an answer (I have to admit I didn't think it would be hard at first).

I have doubts on some existing java methods and I wanted to know if there is a way to open an existing class, I'm using Eclipse and I remember I was able some years ago to open a given existing class but it seems like I can't do that anymore I'm getting "Source not found" when double click on a method.

For example I needed to know how is implemented `bufferedImage.getWidth()`, how could I do that?

I checked on javadocs online but it doesn't contains the content of the files, only description..

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: By doubts I mean 'about time complexity' ^^

Comment: If you have a JDK installed (rather than a JRE) this should be automatic.

Comment: Double-clicking is not how you open a method. Navigate->Open Declaration or hold down Ctrl/Cmd and click on it like a hyperlink.

Comment: Neither of these work for me, just found out I have no JDK installed, didn't know it was possible to code without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select this method with your cursor and then click ctrl + 3 a small window with a search bar will pop-up. In the search bar look for get.Width if you click the get.Width option it will take you to the documentation of this method.